# Latest hour unique entries MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I want to have the latest hour unique entries

This query gives me the latest unique entries (but not of the last hour):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM allSensors t1
  JOIN (SELECT uniqueID, MAX(timestamp) timestamp FROM allSensors GROUP BY uniqueID) t2
    ON t1.uniqueID = t2.uniqueID AND t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp;
```

This query gives me the latest hour entries (but not all of them are unique):

```
SELECT * FROM allSensors WHERE timeStamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

How could I get the latest hour latest entries?
How could I get this done with maximum performance??
This will be requested every 5 seconds! And the table has them all

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `allSensors` (
  `timeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `DeviceID` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `UniqueID` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DataAge` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Temp` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Light` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Humid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeafTemp` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SoilHumid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SoilEC` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Batt` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SNR` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ts` double DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: Can you explain your table schema and show sample data for the table and the result you would like to achieve?  Just giving us some SQL statements without any additional context is going to make it more difficult to get optimal answer.

Comment: Please post the results of `show create table allSensors\G` and `explain <your query>;`

Comment: Some specifics would help as well. # of uniqueIds, # of timestamps per uniqueId, typical # of timestamps per hour. If several seconds is not acceptable, what is the acceptable/expected runtime?

Comment: You probably want timestamp as an index and it will get quite large depending on how much data you have. Also considering archiving yesterday's data daily. Another option is partitioning the table which I think is available in modern mysql.

Comment: Updated as you requested sorry for missing some information.

Comment: In what way is the second query returning non-unique rows? Please post a result set.

Comment: `DOUBLE`?  That's 8 bytes.  A 4-byte `FLOAT` has more precision than most of those fields can ever have.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t1.*
    FROM  allSensors t1
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  uniqueID, MAX(timestamp) timestamp
            FROM  allSensors
            GROUP BY  uniqueID
      ) t2 ON t2.uniqueID = t1.uniqueID
         AND  t2.timestamp = t1.timestamp;
    WHERE     t2.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

That is, get all the last ids, but then throw away the ones that are too old.

You need the composite `INDEX(uniqueID, timestamp)` (in that order).

Comment: Thanks Rick, unfortunately I don't undertand what you mean with: the composite and with two different queries (since they are separated by ";") Performance is a must so we should first get the last hour readings and then select the latest unique.